# Fortran Module Global Variable

Tags: function, generics, module, fortran

I am encountering the following error when calling the function convert. The function
is a generic name in a fortran module.

```
gfortran -o build/lib/foul.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/foul.f
gfortran -o build/lib/meidum.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/meidum.f
lib/meidum.f:55.23:

Real :: right_angl = convert (90.0, "angle: deg_to_rad")
                   1
Error: There is no specific function for the generic 'convert' at (1)
```

Here is the defining part of the module. There is a convert function for different
data types which are real, double precision, and quadruple precision.

```
Module Meidum

Use Foul
Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
Implicit None

Interface convert
  Module Procedure convert
  Module Procedure convert_dble
  Module Procedure convert_real128
End Interface convert

Real :: right_angl = convert (90.0, "angle: deg_to_rad")

Contains 

...


Function convert   &
  (                &
    qa, label      &
  )                &
    Result (qb)

Real, Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Real :: qb

If (label .contains. "angle:") Then

 Block

   Real :: pi
   Real :: deg_to_rad, grad_to_rad, grad_to_deg

   pi = 22.0 / 7.0
   deg_to_rad  = pi  / 180.0
   grad_to_rad = pi  / 200.0
   grad_to_deg = 9.0 / 10.0

   Select Case (Trim (label))

     Case ("angle: deg_to_rad")
       qb = deg_to_rad * qa

     Case ("angle: grad_to_rad")
       qb = grad_to_rad * qa

     Case ("angle: grad_to_deg")
       qb = grad_to_deg * qa

     Case ("angle: rad_to_deg")
       qb = qa / deg_to_rad 

     Case ("angle: rad_to_grad")
       qb = qa / grad_to_rad

       Case ("angle: deg_to_grad")
         qb = qa / grad_to_deg

      End Select

    End Block

  End If

End Function convert



Function convert_dble  &
  (                    &
    qa, label          &
  )                    &
    Result (qb)

Double Precision, Intent (in) :: qa
Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

Double Precision :: qb

...

End Function convert_dble



Function convert_real128  &
  (                       &
    qa, label             &
  )                       &
    Result (qb)

  Real (Real128), Intent (in) :: qa
  Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: label

  Real (Real128) :: qb

End Function convert_real128
```

Comment: Show the specification parts of the specific procedures that are part of the `convert` generic interface.  The error is a simple one - your function reference has a mismatch in the number or types of arguments against all of those specific procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is perhaps a distraction.

The initializer for a variable has to be what is called a constant expression in Fortran 2008 (an initialization expression in older versions).  This is basically an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.  A user defined function is not permitted in a constant expression (evaluating the function requires the function to be executed, which is not something that can typically be done at compile time).

You need to make the statement that gives the `right_angl` variable its value an executable statement of some sort - in some cases this is done by having an "Intialise" or similar procedure in the module that must be called before anything else from the module can be used.

Comment: Hi Ian, I would think it might be non-intuitive for the programmer to remember to call it. Do you agree?

Comment: No.  Requiring some sort of initialization procedure to be called before other procedures and types in a package can be used is quite common.

Comment: I suppose I would have to flag a warning if that is not done.